# Box plot with pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I am trying to plot a simple boxplot for a large dataset(more than one million records) that I converted from pyspark to pandas to perform some preliminary data analysis. The problem is that when I try to visualize one of the feature with a boxplot the y axis does not reflect the real values(or at least it rescale everything I think).

```
# Describe basic statistics for the features (1)
DF.select('#followers', '#friends', '#favorites').describe().show()
```

[image]

```
df_pandas = DF.toPandas()

fig = plt.figure(figsize =(10, 7))
 
# Creating plot
plt.boxplot(df_pandas["#followers"])
 
# show plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding `plt.yscale('log')`. `'followers'` seems to have a number of outliers that are significantly greater than the mean, so the boxplot is squished because of the yscale.

Comment: What do you mean it tries to rescale the data? You have a maximum value of 110 million, and the y-scale goes up to ~1.2e8 (i.e. 120 million), which seems right to me.

Comment: `plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', useOffset=False, axis='y')` if you don't want the yaxis to use scientific notation.